# HTML video not working in Beaker Browser (P2P)

Tags: html, video, p2p

I'm creating a website and tried inserting videos to no avail. I'm creating this site in a Beaker Browser. Here's my code:

```
  <body>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls  autoplay loop>
    <source src="videos/videotest.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    <source src="videos/videotest.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <source src="videos/videotest.webm" type="video/webm" />
    </video>
  </body>
```

I've checked the path of the folder and tried deleting the file and ultimately uploading it again.Also I've tried deleting some "" to see if it would work:

```
    <body>
      <video width="320" height="240" controls  autoplay loop>
      <source src="videos/videotest.mp4" type=video/mp4 >
      <source src="videos/videotest.ogv" type=video/ogg />
      <source src="videos/videotest.webm" type=video/webm />
      </video>
    </body>
```

I've no idea what's wrong. Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per the current bugs for the project, `<video>` isn't supported - https://github.com/beakerbrowser/beaker/issues/1560